# Mapping the output of one table to multiple objects using Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

Say, I have a table with the following structure

```
CONTINENT COUNTRY CAPITAL CITY        POPULATION
--------- ------- ------- ----        ----------
EUROPE    UK      LONDON  LONDON      4234323
EUROPE    UK      LONDON  BIRMINGHAM  432432
EUROPE    GERMANY BERLIN  BERLIN      24342342
EUROPE    GERMANY BERLIN  MUNICH      343433
ASIA      CHINA   BEIJING BEIJING     543345453
ASIA      CHINA   BEIJING SHANGHAI    432434233
ASIA      JAPAN   TOKYO   TOKYO       43232333
```

And my classes looks

```
class Continent {
    String name;
    List<Country> countries;
}

class Country {
    String capitalCityName;
    List<City> cities;
}

class City {
    String name;
    Long population;
}
```

What is the best way I can select the rows from the above table and populate it into my classes using JDBC Template? I know that the database table isn't normalized, but I need to live with that due to legacy support reasons.

Comment: And your best attempt's code is?

Comment: to use a ResultSetExtractor, looping through every row for a City and checking if that City has already been added to a Country, and looping through every Country to see if it has been added to the Conitnent...in short, very ugly

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to add

```
select distinct * 
from t 
ORDER BY CONTINENT, COUNTRY, CITY
```

Then all you need is to create a new Continent when continent name is changed, create Country when country name is changed.

For each row a City is created and added to current Country.

This way one loop is enough.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is using the **BeanPropertyRowMapper** class. Though there are other ways to do this.

So for Example, In your case, to fetch the Country data, You can do something like this :

```
public List<Country> getCountries(){

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM COUNTRY";

    List<Country> countries  = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Country.class));

    return countries;
}
```